# shouldRetryException when making JSON web request in android

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to get the json data from below URL

> https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=apple&from=2022-01-01&to=2022-01-01&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=myApiKey

But getting the following error:

```
E/Volley: [4982] NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException: Unexpected response code 403
```

Here is the code

```
private lateinit var mAdapter: NewsListAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    fetchData()
    mAdapter = NewsListAdapter(this)
    recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
}

private fun fetchData() {
    val url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=apple&from=2022-01-01&to=2022-01-01&sortBy=popularity&apiKey=myApiKey"
    val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(
        Request.Method.GET,
        url,
        null,
        {
            val newsJsonArray = it.getJSONArray("articles")
            val newsArray = ArrayList<News>()
            for(i in 0 until newsJsonArray.length()) {
                val newsJsonObject = newsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i)
                val news = News(
                    newsJsonObject.getString("title"),
                    newsJsonObject.getString("author"),
                    newsJsonObject.getString("url"),
                    newsJsonObject.getString("urlToImage")
                )
                newsArray.add(news)
            }

            mAdapter.updateNews(newsArray)
        },
        {

        }
    )
    MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest)
}

override fun onItemClicked(item: News) {
    val builder =  CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
    val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(item.url))
}
fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
    headers["User-Agent"]="Mozilla/5.0"
    return headers
}
```

Comment: You tagged Java, but that is not Java code that you have posted. Please use tags appropriately.

Comment: I note that the link in the question contains an invalid ">" at the end and the link in the code contains an invalid "\n" at the end.

Comment: @Codo Still the same error after removing ">" and "\n"

Comment: Have you copied the code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67780323/e-volley-44820-network-utility-should-retry-exception-unexpected-response-c? If so, the function `getHeaders()` is now in the wrong place and will never be called.